# wordpress create page without dashboard or admin url

Tags: wordpress, url, plugins, dashboard

sorry for my poor english. I installed a plugin Remove Dashboard Access to prevent users to access the dashboard , but I still want the users create pages or posts , now if I active the plugin users can't create page or post and if I deactivate the plugin users will access to dashboard.
how can"t prevent users from accessing dashboard and let them add pages or posts without passing by wp-admin url

Thank you

Comment: You need to create a custom login page / form , after login succeed redirect users to a custom page / script that has a function to create pages / posts. I think that's the step. You also need to restrict non administrator to access wp-admin

Answer (score 3):

You just need to install a plug-in see the link below.

WP User Frontend
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/